Odoo 17 issue : Uncaught Promise > Invalid props for component 'OptionalFieldsDropdown'
Am working on Odoo 17 enterprise.
I get this issue when am with mode debug when i tried to enter to sales module, without mode debug on it works fine.
Anyone have any idea how i resolve that.
Thank you.
i tried to enter to sales module
enter image description here
